# Is it possible to store commas instead of points for decimal fields in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, decimal, field

Is it possible to store commas instead of points for decimal fields in a PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has nothing to do with PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL does not store commas or points for decimal fields. It uses an internal number representation for numbers (int, floats, numeric).

If you need to format numeric information with PostgreSQL, you can use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) function or use your client side programming language to format numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Why? No programming language will accept decimals using comma's as a seperator. Presentation should be done in the presentation layer of your application, not in the storage layer.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had the same feeling about this, but I wanted to hear a good explanation. Tnx!