# function that read decimal number and parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

i want this function read a decimal number like '10,5' and a parameter like 'en'.

query i use:

```
select nombreenlettre1(10,5,'en')
```

see query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5282e21a6363acf3cc6f8e0b9bc575ae

error returned:

```
ERROR:  function nombreenlettre1(integer, integer, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select nombreenlettre1(10,5,'en')
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Use decimal separator `.` i.e. `10.5` when passing the number. You are telling it to pass 2 numbers and a string to `nombreenlettre1()`, but it was not declared as taking that many arguments, nor do you really want to separate the `10` and `5`. Isn't the error clear about that?

Comment: no, i want to use 10,5

Comment: Well, you just can't. The language expects a `.` as point, not a `,`. You have to write what the language wants, not what you want. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096329/is-it-possible-to-store-commas-instead-of-points-for-decimal-fields-in-a-postgre

Comment: in this case, how can i convert to return 10.5